# Is there any disadvantages with using createNativeQuery() method of JPA

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I have a big query with so many joins and I have tried for JPQL implementation (using createQuery() method)of the query but I am getting so many syntax problems with usage of entities instead of table names. So I have chosen native query implementation as it is executing my query properly on my Oracle DB.
Is native query is DB specific? and If we change the DB from Oracle to other DB like MySql or SQLServer, will it work?. Please help me on this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page that shows some differences among mysql, Oracle, and mssql:

http://www.bristle.com/Tips/SQL.htm#differences_in_sql_syntax

You can see that there are differences in the way certain kinds of joins are specified.

So yes, you may have problems with complex queries if you choose to use the native query implementation and the switch databases.

Comment: If possible can you provide me a JPQL query with some joins?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post a question with your sql query and your attempts at using jpql.

Comment: Hi Robert,                                                                                              Below is the actual query I am trying to implement in JPQL

Comment: select req.transactiontime, c.claimid as referral_number, 
rslt.failure_reason_code,cl.servicedate, cl.clmline_index,rslt_line.failure_reason_code,exp.explanation_code,
from pricreq req join prof_claim c on (c.id = req.prfclm_id) join prof_cl_line cl on (c.id = cl.owner_id) 
join pricresult rslt on (req.systemid = rslt.systemid and req.requestid = rslt.requestid)
join pricresult rslt_line on (rslt.id = rslt_line.claimres_id) 
left outer join pricresultexp exp on (rslt_line.id = exp.lineresult_id)
where cl.clmline_index = rslt_line.clmlinepri_index

Comment: Post a new question, you'll have a much better chance of getting an answer.